# In vert.x, does it make sense to create multiple HttpServer instances in a runtime?

Tags: vert.x

I created a verticle named `HttpServerVerticle` and inside it let it create a `HttpServer` instance by `vertx.createHttpServer()`, then in my main verticle I deployed this HTTP verticle with > 1 instances by `vertx.deployVerticle("xxx.xxx.HttpServerVerticle", deploymentOptionsOf(instances = 2))`.

Does it make sense to have multiple `HttpServer` instances in a runtime? If it does, why I did not see similar error messages like "8080 port is already in use"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vert.x will actually [round-robin between your `HttpServer` instances listening on the same port](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_server_shar%60ing):

> When several HTTP servers listen on the same port, vert.x orchestrates the request handling using a round-robin strategy...
>
> So, when [a] verticle is instantiated multiple times as with: `vertx run io.vertx.examples.http.sharing.HttpServerVerticle -instances 2`, what’s happening? If both verticles would bind to the same port, you would receive a socket exception. Fortunately, vert.x is handling this case for you. When you deploy another server on the same host and port as an existing server it doesn’t actually try and create a new server listening on the same host/port. It binds only once to the socket. When receiving a request it calls the server handlers following a round robin strategy...
>
> Consequently the servers can scale over available cores while each Vert.x verticle instance remains strictly single threaded, and you don’t have to do any special tricks like writing load-balancers in order to scale your server on your multi-core machine.

So it is both safe and encouraged to creating multiple instances of HttpServers, if required to scale across cores.